# JavaScript function returning "undefined"

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple code to choose random name from four, using "random_word();" function and it doesn't work. It says:"undefined". Can anyone explain me why and help to fix it? Thanks for all help.

```
var randomWord;

var word = new Array(3);
word[0] = "Michael";
word[1] = "Simon";
word[2] = "Peter";
word[3] = "Mark";

function random_word(){
var randomWord = word[Math.floor(Math.random()*word.length)]
}

random_word();

document.write(randomWord);
```

Comment: btw, the array declaration with `3` makes no sense, because the assignment has 4 items.

Comment: If you're learning Javascript, make sure to use recent references and tutorials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make `randomWord` to a private variable of the function with a `var` statement. Without, you could use the global variable for the result.

```js
function random_word() {
    randomWord = word[Math.floor(Math.random() * word.length)];
}

var randomWord;
    word = ["Michael", "Simon", "Peter", "Mark"];

random_word();
document.write(randomWord);
```

A better style and more concise would be the return of the selected item. An even better version, would be if you use the array as parameter as well, because you could use the function for other arrays as well.

```js
function getRandomItem(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

var words = ["Michael", "Simon", "Peter", "Mark"];

document.write(getRandomItem(words));
```

Bonus, add random name with interval.

```js
function getRandomItem(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

var words = ["Michael", "Simon", "Peter", "Mark"];

setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById('names').innerHTML += getRandomItem(words) + '<br>';
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div id="names"></div>
```

Comment: (Option 1) - Cool. I have one more question. If I put "document.write(randomWord);" into a "write()" funtion and add "setInterval(write, 2000);" at the end of the code it chooses random word from this four. But if I would like it to choose random name every time (every 2 sec in this case) what i suppose to do?

Comment: Thank you. Or maybe: Danke schön :)

Answer (score 3):

The local variable `randomWord` in the `random_word` function context has nothing to do with the `randomWord` declared in the outer context. If you want to reset the value of the outer context `randomWord` variable then you should drop the `var` keyword in your function.

```
function random_word(){
    randomWord = word[Math.floor(Math.random()*word.length)]
}
```

But this is not a good way of programming. Ideally the function should return a value.

```
function random_word(){
  return word[Math.floor(Math.random()*word.length)];
}

var randomWord = random_word();
var anotherRandomWord = random_word();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using var keyword in your function which creates a local variable. When you get out of that function the global one is not set.

Use this instead:

```
function random_word(){  
    randomWord = word[Math.floor(Math.random()*word.length)]
}
```